# unattended-upgrades does not fetch updates unless running apt-get update beforhand

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, unattended-upgrades

Trying to achieve "automatic updates" on a private debian repository using `unattended-upgrades`

Tried checking [1755716](https://askubuntu.com/q/1336631/1755716) suggested solution with no success

The issue is new versions are not fetched & installed unless running `apt update` beforehand

It does works manually - running `apt update && apt update X` and the new version was installed successfully

Tried running `unattended-upgrades` command manually -> showing no available updates

```
sudo unattended-upgrades -v
Starting unattended upgrades script
Allowed origins are: o=Artifactory,a=bionic, o=Ubuntu,a=jammy, o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-security, o=UbuntuESMApps,a=jammy-apps-security, o=UbuntuESM,a=jammy-infra-security, o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-updates
Initial blacklist:
Initial whitelist (not strict):
No packages found that can be upgraded unattended and no pending auto-removals
```

My config/setup

`/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades`

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins {
        "Artifactory bionic"; // My custom repository
        "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}";
        "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-security";
        "${distro_id}ESMApps:${distro_codename}-apps-security";
        "${distro_id}ESM:${distro_codename}-infra-security";
        "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-updates";
};

Unattended-Upgrade::Package-Blacklist {
};

Unattended-Upgrade::DevRelease "false";

Unattended-Upgrade::Remove-Unused-Kernel-Packages "true";

Unattended-Upgrade::Remove-Unused-Dependencies "true";

Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot "true";
```

`/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic`

```
APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "1";
APT::Periodic::Download-Upgradeable-Packages "0";
APT::Periodic::AutocleanInterval "0";
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "1";
```

added my repo to `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
deb [trusted=yes] https://x:x@x.jfrog.io/artifactory/bodel bionic main
```

```
systemctl list-timers | grep apt
Sun 2024-01-07 21:46:23 UTC 9h left     Thu 2024-01-04 17:25:55 UTC 2 days ago   apt-daily.timer                apt-daily.service
Mon 2024-01-08 06:57:49 UTC 18h left    Sun 2024-01-07 10:36:13 UTC 2h 9min ago  apt-daily-upgrade.timer        apt-daily-upgrade.service
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, try added and re-run `sudo unattended-upgrades -v` but got the same result -> `No packages found that can be upgraded unattended and no pending auto-removals`

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1499293/edit) to show the complete output of `systemctl list-timers | grep apt`

Comment: @user535733 done

Comment: @mook765 thanks for the suggestion, see `Allowed-Origins` -> it's already containing my package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output shows nothing wrong. Everything looks fine, including your Artifactory source.

When you run `unattended-upgrade` manually, it's **not** running `apt update`. So your database of packages might be older than you expect, or you might see different packages than expected on the list of upgrades.

You know from using apt that two actions are required for updates:

- Update the database of available packages (`apt update` and `apt-daily.service`)
- Search the updated database for upgraded packages, download, and install (`apt upgrade` and `apt-daily-upgrade.service` and `unattended-upgrade`)

The key here is that the `unattended-upgrade` command does **not** do both. It only runs the second (upgrade). It does **not** update the database first.

For the normal usage of Unattended Upgrades, this is adequate to keep your Ubuntu system packages up to date completely automatically within 24-48 hours of release.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer !
so from what I understand it's just a matter of time for this package to be upgraded .. 
what the "best practice" to make this "update & upgrade" cycle more frequent ? I assume adjusting `apt-daily.timer` and `apt-daily.timer`